# What are the major interpretations of the Enuma Elish?

Tags: interpretation, mesopotamia

I'm reading Mesopotamian mythology and looking to get a  comparison of the major interpretations of the 'meaning' (mythological, psychological or psychoanalytic, ecological, historical, etc.) of the Enuma Enlish creation story, and the slaying of Apsu and Tiamat, so I can have a comparative scholarly framework in the back of my mind as I go. Thanks for your time.